# how to add some product are printable and some not in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

What is the use of "this product is printable"? 
And some product not display icon of print.
How to implement in magento?
See design of magento layout product list page.

[image]

Comment: As I remember magento doesn't have such native functionality. Most probably it refers to your custom theme or some of your custom extensions. If you tell us where it implemented - we can answer on your question. Try to search at design folder for *This product is printable* and upload text of this template and path to this template

Comment: This image is design(PSD).I have created my new custome theme.I am new in magento.I found this plugin http://blog.chapagain.com.np/print-product-cart-page-magento-extension-free/ but it is apply to all products.

Comment: So your general question how to add some setting to the product to enable or disable print page for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create new attribute for all type of products which you want to have this option. Type of the attribute should be **yes/no**. Most of other options are not important except following:

**Visible on Product View Page on Front-end** should equals **Yes**

[image]

Then you need to open

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/clearprint/catalog/product/view/printlink.phtml

And wrap existing content in condition, like this `$_product->getData('your_new_attribute_name')`

You will have smth like this:

```
<?php if ($this->helper('clearprint')->isEnabledPrintProduct()): ?>

    <?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $url = "clearprint/catalog_product/view/".$_product->getEntityId();
    $buttonTitle = $this->__('Print Product');
    ?>

    <?php /*
    <button style="margin-left:2px" type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick='window.open("<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB).'clearprint/catalog_product/view/id/'.$_product->getEntityId() ?>", "_blank", "toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0");'><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
    */ ?>

            <?php if ($_product->getData('your_new_attribute_name')) : ?>

    <ul class="add-to-links">   
        <li style="margin-left:5px"><a href="#" onclick='window.open("<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl().'clearprint/catalog_product/view/id/'.$_product->getEntityId() //echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB).'clearprint/catalog_product/view/id/'.$_product->getEntityId() ?>", "_blank", "toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0");' class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Print Product') ?></a></li>
    </ul>

            <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

After you did it - you need to set this param to yes for all products which you like to be printable. You can do it via massUpdate on product grid.

Comment: Thank you very much.It display product detail page.how to display product list page?

Comment: looks like this extension doesn't support it and need to be customized. It's hard to advice how to implement it. I can offer you a solution, but I suppose that this customization can require much development time.

Comment: Ok.Thank You.:)